Is there a way in prometheus to count how many records exists using promQl?
I have been using Prometheus as a data source in Grafana lately, but there are so many limitation to Prometheus. for example have a look at these records that exists in my localhost:9090 where Prometheus located: enter image description here. This image shows some of my records in one of my targets. Can you help me write a query using promQl that can return to me the number of records appeared in last 5 minutes for example?
Can you help me write a query using promQl that can return to me the number of records appeared in last 5 minutes for example?

count_over_time(http_requests_total[5m])
see promql examples and promql cheat sheet

I am trying to do this query: count_over_time(api_transactions_count_combined{username="GUPTA1585", environment="development"}[$__range])
to count how many record or http_request with some conditions happened in a specific period of time but when i do it in grafana (gauge visualization), it is showing me random data with a lot of instances. I just want a single number representing how many http records happend in last 5 minutes as an example

Can you update your question with a visual of what you are seeing in grafana? Also what type graph are you displaying?

Try the following PromQL query:
sum(
  increase(
    api_transactions_count_combined{
      username="GUPTA1585", environment="development"
    }[$__range]
  )
)

This query returns the total number of events registered in  api_transactions_count_combined counter time series over the time range selected in Grafana (aka $__range).
If the api_transactions_count_combined is a gauge, then the query should look like the following:
sum(
  sum_over_time(
    api_transactions_count_combined{
      username="GUPTA1585", environment="development"
    }[$__range]
  )
)

This query replaces increase() function with sum_over_time() function.
Both queries use sum() function for summing per-time series results into a single value.
